# Collated and separated results in one cell for QUERY results across multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

In a Google Sheet I have the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(QUERY(Summary!I4:U200,"Select I,U where S='"&A3&"'"))
```

This currently returns each pair of results in sequence (with no spaces) and in a single cell, as in (assuming 3 results on sheet "Summary"):

```
A1B1A2B2A3B3
```

But I would like the results returned separated, as in:

```
A1/B1, A2/B2, A3/B3
```

I tried using JOIN as in:

```
=JOIN(", ",(QUERY(Summary!I4:U200,"Select I,U where S='"&A3&"'")))
```

But this returns the following error:

> JOIN range must be a single row or single column.

I tried exploring various solutions (e.g. using array formulas and also using SPLIT), but I can't get the result I want.

Anyone?

Comment: An array should work, can you try a text join and array instead?

Comment: Can you give an example formula?

Answer (score 5):

Try `=TEXTJOIN`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" , ", TRUE,QUERY(A1:C4, "Select *"),0 ))
```

I'm not sure why JOIN doesn't work but I find `TEXTJOIN` works a little better.

Comment: @Datanovice.I hadn't thought of using TEXTJOIN. That gets me closer, but still not quite there.

Comment: Meant to also add:
The following (slightly modified from what you suggested):
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE,QUERY(Sheet1!A1:E20,"Select B,C where A="&A2&"")))
Returns each pair of (B & C) results in sequence separated by the TEXTJOIN specified delimiter (in this case a comma), but there is no delimiter to distinguish one pair from another, i.e. results show as:
 , ,A1,B1,A2,B2,A3,B3,
Rather than (what I’d like):
A1/B1, A2/B2, A3/B3
Also, note that curiously the results start with a pair of white spaces separated by a comma.

Comment: Can you split A1B1 then reapply a new delimiter? Can you make a spreadsheet with your desired output? I'm having a hard time putting a picture to your issue!

Comment: =ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE,QUERY(Sheet1!A2:E20,"Select B,C where A='"&A2&"'")))

Comment: Also... =ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE,QUERY(Sheet1!A2:E20,"Select B,C where A='"&A2&"'"))) Gives B1,C1,B2,C2,B3,C3, but I want B1/C1, B2/C2, B3/C3 (i.e. both collate and separate the query results and output to a single cell). Using TEXTJOIN gets closer (i.e. before I had C1B1C2B2C3B3), but the pairs are still not distinguished from one another. I don't know how to add a SPLIT function to the formula that would also split by every second delimiter. Example sheet I made to illustrate: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bq3LHgGcVeCoS4QgNZYh6qaYunjwd3OkoLeMCtDCvJs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you allowed a helper column?